# Connecting Wikijs to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect Wiki.js to a MySQL database in which I can add documents and stuff. In this, the guide tells me to make a config file, shown below.

```
db:
  type: mysql
  host: localhost
  port: 443
  user: root
  pass: password
  db: wikijs
  ssl: false
```

Upon trying to connect I get the following error message;

2022-10-22T11:13:08.937Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: ETIMEDOUT undefined:undefined
2022-10-22T11:13:08.937Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt *x* of 10]

[Powershell Image of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u0Dn.png)

[Full PowershellOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsQQN.png)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Added the full output

Comment: Most MySql servers use port 3306. It would be very strange indeed to serve the mySql protocol over port 443. Try 3306, or simply omit the port.

Comment: Fixed. Wrong port was put in the file. Port 443 was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Port 443 was the incorrect port. Switching it to 3306 fixed the problem.